# Reindexing with date range to add missing dates in time series data results in an empty data frame

Tags: python, pandas, time, series

I have a Pandas data frame that looks like this:

|  | Date | Total Absences |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 17 | 2022-01-03 | 7 |
| 18 | 2022-01-04 | 16 |
| 19 | 2022-01-05 | 18 |
| 20 | 2022-01-07 | 18 |

and so on.....

As this data only has information from weekdays and I would like to do a time series analysis which requires regularity in the time intervals, I am looking to Pad the missing values with a 0.

However, when I run the below code, it results in an empty data frame:

```
    #As the data doesn't have regular intervals, for example, weekends and holidays, we will need to pad those values. 

all_dates = pd.date_range(2022-1-1, 2022-5-31, freq = "D")
data.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(data.index)
data = data.reindex(all_dates, fill_value=0)

print(data)
```

This is the output:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AuPd.png)

The desired Output is this:

|  | Date | Total Absences |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 17 | 2022-01-01 | 0 |
| 18 | 2022-01-02 | 0 |
| 19 | 2022-01-03 | 7 |
| 20 | 2022-01-04 | 16 |
| 21 | 2022-01-05 | 18 |
| 22 | 2022-01-06 | 0 |
| 23 | 2022-01-07 | 18 |

Please let me know where I am going wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please add the dataframe into the question as a table and not an image? And also add your desired output.

Comment: It is mistake - first date is `2022-1-1`, maybe need `pd.date_range('1984-01-01', '2022-05-31', freq = "D")`

Comment: @Zero: Added the dataframe as a table and the desired output.

Comment: @jezrael: Thanks for your reply. The 1984 values were removed because they didn't make sense. The data is supposed to start from Jan 1, 2022.

Comment: In sample data is not `DatetimeIndex`, so need `data = data .set_index('Data')` and then `data.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(data.index)`